# cnf: proving logical implication of satisfiability

Tags: logic

I tried solving the below problem, but in the textbook there wasn't even an example how to solve a similar problem. All my ad-hoc attempts at solving it turned null.

Can someone show me how to solve it, so I can test myself on similar problems?

**PROBLEM:** "Given a disjunction D of four or more literals:

$L_1 \cup L_2 \cup ... \cup L_n$,

let

$C_1, ..., C_{n-2}$

be statement letters that do not occur in D, and construct
the cnf E:

$(L_1 \cup L_2 \cup C_1)$ ^ $(-C_1 \cup L_3 \cup C_2)$ ^ $(-C_2 \cup L_4 \cup C_3)$ ^ ...
^ $(-C_{n-3} \cup L_{n-1} \cup C_{n-2})$ ^ $(-C_{n-2} \cup L_n \cup -C_1)$

Show that any truth assignment satisfying D can be extended to a
truth assignment satisfying E and, conversely, any truth assignment
satisfying E is an extension of a truth assignment satisfying D.

(This
permits the reduction of the problem of satisfying cnfs to the corresponding
problem for cnfs with each conjunct containing at most
three literals.)"

Comment: So is $n$ at least 3? I am a bit confused to the pattern of E... how does E look for n = 3?

Comment: @Ove I am just as confused. I wrote it exactly as it was in the textbook.

Answer (score 0):

So there are two directions to prove here.

> 1. Show that any assignment satisfying E can be extended to an assignment satisfying D.

Assume that $v$ is a truthassignments such that $v(E)=T$ but $v(D)=F$. Thus for each $i$, $v(L_i) = F$. However then note what happens in $E$: $v(L_1 \vee L_2 \vee C_1) = T$ and thus $v(C_1)= T$. Now by induction we can show that $v(C_k)=T$ for each $k\leq (n-2)$ by looking at $E$ truncated to the first $k$ conjunctions. However The last conjunction in E $v(\neg C_{n-2} \vee L_n \vee \neg C_1) = F$ and we thus conclude that $v(E) = F$ which is a contradiction. Hence Each assignment such that $v(E) =T$ implies $v(D)=T$.

> 2. Show that any assignment satisfying D can be extended to an assignment satisfying E.

Assume $v$ is a truthassignment such that $v(D)=T$. Thus for some $i$, $v(L_i)=T$.

a) Assume $i>2$: Extend $v$ such that $v(C_j) = T$ for each $j<i-1$ and $v(C_j)=F$ for each $j\geq i-1$. Now $v(L_1\vee L_2\vee C_1) = T$, if $j<i-1$ then $v(\neg C_{j-2} \vee L_j \vee C_{j-1}) = T$ and if $j\geq i-1$ then $v(\neg C_{j-2} \vee L_j \vee C_{j-1}) = T$. Thus $v(E)=T$.

b) Assume i=1 or $i=2$ then just let $v(C_j)=F$ for each j, and we may quickly verify that $v(E)=T$.

This completes the proof.